# Why BIC tends to choose model with less parameters than AIC?

Tags: aic, bic

I understand that the AIC penalizes the number of parameters less strongly than the BIC. Then it's concluded that the BIC tends to choose model with less parameters. Why penalizing strongly will lead to less parameters?

Answer (score 2):

You've answered your own question. BIC chooses favors more parsimonious models *because it penalises the number of parameters more strongly than AIC does*.

The formula for AIC is

2k - 2ln(L)

and BIC is

ln(n)k + 2ln(L)

Where k is the number of parameters. Only the penalty term differs between each formula, while the goodness of fit parts remain the same. BIC's penalty term grows more sharply than AIC's as the number of parameters increase. Therefore, BIC will choose the more parsimonious model.

Comment: Thanks. But why growing more sharply will lead to more parsimonious model?

Comment: Because we choose the model with the lowest BIC. A 'good' model is one with a low BIC. A model with a low BIC will typically have fewer parameters

Comment: Your formula for the AIC is specific only to the case of normal errors linear regression. In general the second term should be twice the maximized log likelihood.

Comment: Is there any mathematical proof to show BIC will lead to parsimonious model? BIC and AIC both have two parts. The goodness of fit part decreases with k, the number of parameters, with different speed (?). The penalty part increases with k. The penalty part of BIC increases more sharply than AIC does. Then why the minimum of BIC is associated with a smaller k?

Comment: @cheezit, the goodness of fit parts are exactly the same in both equations, although this is obscured by what Conor Neilson wrote. Therefore the only difference is the penalty term, which is larger for the BIC (well, at least if $n>7$). Is it clear now why BIC forces greater parsimony?

Comment: @gammer Thanks. Almost there. Suppose f(k) denotes the goodness of fit. Let's view AIC and BIC as a continuous function of k. We want the minimum. AIC: f'(k)+2=0; BIC: f'(k)+ln(L)=0. Do we have any information on f'(k) except it's negative?

Comment: thats the wrong formula for AIC. It should be AIC=2(k-L) and BIC=log(n)k -2L. If they both equal zero for some reason then evidently k=L and log(n)=2.

Comment: Did you miss the goodness of fit part? This part should be a function of k since its value decreases with k.

Comment: $k$ is the number of parameters. You calculate the AIC/BIC for a model fit to a fixed number of parameters. So $k$ is fixed. $L$ increases (not decreases) when you add parameters (i.e. increase $k$). AIC requires a smaller likelihood increase for each additional parameter than BIC does.